# How to brute force and open a protected android app using scrcpy

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I have an app which i wanted to view on my linux desktop, using scrcpy.
All the android app contents(inside the app) are visible in my scrcpy desktop, except when i open PDF's from that app.
when i open a pdf from that app, im getting this error message:

```
Please turn off usb debugging under developer options to view protected content
```

Is there any way to open access to it?
I simply wanted to take screenshots of reading materials from that app. Its also not allowing me to take screenshot.

I wanted to make knowledge free, can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

it's a circular problem. You cant use scrcpy without USB debugging and you cannot see the content with USB debugging. I'm guessing it does not let you take screenshots on an actual phone as well.

This is not an answer but I think the only was is to take a photo from a second phone or reverse enginner the app and comment out the FLAG_SECURE section in your code and re run